# Named Lists - Partial name matching

Tags: r

```
test <- list()
test$sammy <- 10
test$bobby <- 5

test$sam
is.null(test$bob)
```

This produces

```
[1] 10    
[1] FALSE
```

I've been using R for a while and somehow I've never noticed this behaviour. Can this partial name match behaviour be disabled?  Where is it documented?  What is the motivation for this behaviour?

I can check `var %in% names(mylist)` to make sure I dont fall foul of this again, but I would like more about it.

Comment: Workaround, use `test[["sam"]]`.

Comment: Look for `warnPartialMatchDollar` in [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html). As far as I know, it cannot be *disabled*, but it can become noisy. (I'm surprised how many CRAN packages emit warnings on this!)

Comment: Correct workaround is `test[["sam"]]`